# Eventlog or logger class

Tags: .net, logging

I'm working on an application and I'm thinking about implementing a logger so the users of my application can provide log information about what the application was doing if it crashes. I know there is the `EventLog` from Microsoft but this needs administration rights to create one and it's not the purpose of my application that it has to be installed.

So, `EventLog` looks like no option to me so I'm thinking about writing my own `static class Logger` that I can call everywhere in my code. I would add a `public void SetLogLocation(string logLocation)` so I can set my location once when the application is starting. After that I can call `public static Log(string message)` anywhere in my application.

1. Is this a good approach for a logger class or should I instead create a global instance of the logger class where I set the log location there?
2. If I get the logging right, should I write to the log file whenever a line of code is executed or should this be done on the method of methods?

My target is a C# WPF application but this is probably not important.

Comment: Unless you are constrained by some corporate mandate to not use a 3rd party library, then why reinvent the wheel? Use log4net, NLog, Serilog or one of the other popular libraries.